# Can I use Store procedure without EF in .Net, If yes then How?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

1) Can I use Store procedure without EF in .Net, If yes then How??
    I am new in Development,I am developmening windows application, and i am using ADO.Net dataset to access data but now my windows application is running slowly, I want to speed up it data access process...

Comment: See the answer below t learn how to call a SP from ADO.NET, then properly improve your query/sp make the application fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) to execute sql commands and stored procedures. 
But before reading the sample...

**Please note**

The performance of your application usually doesn't change using stored procedure instead of normal command or entity framework. Entity framework doesn't have performance issue itself.
You should find your performance issue some where else.

You can use any good tools in a bad way. So changing the tools is not the ultimate solution. The solution may be using the right tools in right way.

**Stored Procedure Sample**

For example you can see [this sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx):

```
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader reader;

    cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    //If your procedure has parameters you can add parameters too
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameter", "value");


    sqlConnection1.Open();

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

    sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: I am developing windows application with ado.net but now it seem to be run slow, Its take time to fetch and display data, NOW what should i do???? Can i use Entity Framework with Store Procedure... and what will be steps??

Comment: Yes @Reza Aghaei Sir, Now I am using Database first approach in EF with Store Procedure.. Thank  you..